# Two Webcam At Same Time AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

Dear guys , 
Is this possible to stream two webcam at same time in flash !?

I want to use one to track a person from top and one for face detection ?!
I just wonder am i able to use two webcam at same time in as3 or as2 !?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought it would be impossible but I found this link : http://blog.tricedesigns.com/2006/10/multiple-cameras-in-flex-demystifying.html

It's pretty old so I'm not sure it's still working with the latest Flash Player versions

Comment: works like a charm, god damn this adobe annoying documentation